# Reversing up to middle in Prolog list

Tags: prolog

I want to write a function suppose : `half_reverse(L1, L2).`

This function will reverse the elements of (an odd numbered) list `L1`, from 1 to (middle-1) elements and (middle+1) to last element and store the result in `L2`.

Example:
If input : `half_reverse([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],L2)` then
the output will be: `L2 = [3,2,1,4,7,6,5]`.

Comment: This is in its essence the same problem as the "delete middle element".

Answer (score 0):

Edit: former approach was just too ugly to be left alone. But I'm not 100% satisfied with this solution.

```
around(Ori,Del):-
    around(Ori,Ori,Second,First),
    reverse(First,Tsrif),
    append(Tsrif,Second,Del).
around([_],[H|Slow],[H|Wols],[]):-
    reverse(Slow,Wols).
around([_,_|Fast],[H|Slow],Part2,[H|Part1]):-
    around(Fast,Slow,Part2,Part1).

?- around([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],L).
L = [3, 2, 1, 4, 7, 6, 5]
false
```